# Text and matrix side by side

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, matrices

```
\begin{center}
        \[
        $$  [\textbf{u}]=
         \begin{bmatrix}
             u_1  \\
             u_2  \\
             u_3
        \end{bmatrix}$$
        $\in$ $\mathbb{M}_{3\times1}$ 
        \]

    \end{center}
```

I used the above code to print my matrix and text side by side. 
I am getting the error  bad math delimitor. Suggest an alternative for this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct form most likely is:

```
\[    % <--- start of math mode
[\mathbf{u}]=
 \begin{bmatrix}
     u_1  \\
     u_2  \\
     u_3
\end{bmatrix}
    ,\quad \in\mathbb{M}_{3\times 1}
\]    % <--- end of math mode
```

**Note**: you made the same mistake as can be seen in [Missing $ inserted for matrices](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/409205/missing-inserted-for-matrices/). beside this, the use of `$$` in `latex` document is deprecated. instead it use `\[` ... `\]`.

Also `\mathbf{u}` is the right command rather than `\textbf{u}`.

Comment: @AKTomThomas, than you can accept answer (by clicking on check mark at top left side of answer) :-). also see edit of my answer.

Comment: It should probably be `\mathbf{u}`, rather than `\textbf`.

Comment: @egreg, ups, i overlooked this. corrected now. thank you very much!